# Update column in Invoice Table with Payment total from Payments table

Tags: sql, join, sum, sql-update

I've got 2 tables (shown below) - `Invoice` and `Payments`. A single invoice can have multiple payments. I need to `SUM` the total of `PayAmt` from `Payments` and update the `PayTotal` column in the `Invoice` table.

This is NOT working:

```
UPDATE Invoices
SET Invoices.PayTotal = Payments.Total
FROM Invoices 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT InvNum_FK, SUM(PayAmt) as Total
     FROM Payments) ON Invoices.InvNum_PK = Payments.InvNum_FK
```

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Invoices
(
    InvNum_PK nvarchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    InvAmt    money,
    InvDate   date,
    CustName  nvarchar(255),
    PayTotal  money,
    PayCount  int
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Payments
(
    PayNum_PK int PRIMARY KEY,
    InvNum_FK nvarchar(255) 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Invoices(InvNum_PK),
    PayAmt    money,
    PayDate   date,
);

INSERT INTO Invoices 
VALUES ('GLI101', 838.93, '2021-08-01', 'George Washington', 0, 0);
INSERT INTO Invoices 
VALUES ('GLI202', 1280.26, '2021-08-02', 'Abe Lincoln', 0, 0);
INSERT INTO Invoices 
VALUES ('GLI303', 1456.23, '2021-08-03', 'Tom Jefferson', 0, 0);
INSERT INTO Invoices 
VALUES ('GLI404', 1124.97, '2021-08-04', 'Jim Madison', 0, 0);

INSERT INTO Payments VALUES (1, 'GLI101', 223.33, '08/15/2021')
INSERT INTO Payments VALUES (2, 'GLI101', 211.88, '09/16/2021')
INSERT INTO Payments VALUES (3, 'GLI101', 316.44, '09/14/2021')
INSERT INTO Payments VALUES (4, 'GLI404', 415.46, '09/10/2021')
INSERT INTO Payments VALUES (5, 'GLI404', 115.46, '09/04/2021')
```

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing sum over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the sum, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Comment: I'm using a front end (CRUD) that wont create the calculated field value so I need take the calculated value and update a column in the database. I've found many posts on this board  with questions and answers doing the same thing but I can't get any to work.

Comment: Then rather change the tool you access the DB with, if it's insufficient, than to denormalize the DB...

Comment: In a perfect world, I would do just that. Fortunately, I was able to piece together my own answer from the many other solutions posted by people "denormalizing" (not sure if that's actually a word) their DB and like myself doing just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works if anyone looks at this post in the future with the same question:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT InvNum_FK, SUM(PayAmt) AS PayTotal
    FROM Payments
    GROUP BY InvNum_FK)
UPDATE Invoices SET Invoices.PayTotal = cte.PayTotal
FROM Invoices INNER JOIN cte ON Invoices.InvNum_PK = cte.InvNum_FK
```